# example needed of callback function inside for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, callback

I'm looking for something simple and straight forward, most of what I've pulled up on stack isn't quite what I need. I have an array that I want to loop through while calling a function after each iteration. What would that look like?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call an asynchronous function (like xmlhttprequst), wait for it to finish before processing the next element in the array?

Comment: yes something like that. I want the callback to process each row in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  someFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're having problems with this because of the way closures are handled in Javascript. [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) talks about this, in his [book](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/0596517742), by using the example of a function that assigns a click event handler to an array of nodes. The "intuitive" way is:

```
var addHandlers=function(nodes){
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<nodes.length;++i){
        nodes[i].onClick= function {
            alert (i);
        };
    }
};
```

However, this is not correct: each onClick callback will show the same value of `i = nodes.length-1`. This is because the value of `i` is not copied, but referenced in each inner function. The better way would be to create a helper function that returns a callback, something along the lines of the following:

```
var addHandlers = function (nodes) {
    var helper = function (i){
        return function (e){
            alert (i);
        }
    }
    for (int i =0; i<nodes.length();i++){
        nodes [i].onClick=helper (i);
    }
}
```

Plus, this allows you to avoid creating a function at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process one elment of the array to be used in an asynchronous funcion and then process the next next element you can do something like this;

```
function asynchCallback(arrayToProcess,someVar){
  console.log("callback called with parameter:",someVar);
  processArray(arrayToProcess);
}

function processArray(arr){
  if(arr.length===0){
    console.log("done");
    return;
  }
  var someVar=tmp.splice(0,1);
  setTimeout(function(){
    asynchCallback(tmp,someVar[0]);
  },100);
}
//send a copy of the array:
processArray([1,2,3].concat());
```